# Battery notification in every application that is running

Tags: android, power-management

Is it possible to have a battery notification in every application that is running?

For example: If I'm going to run an application like Angry Birds, is it possible to have some sort of a notification that will tell me if there is enough time to continue playing it?

This is one of the objectives in our thesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I'm going to run an application like Angry Birds, is it possible to have some sort of a notification that will tell me if there is enough time to continue playing it?

You can play Angry Birds for a second, a minute, an hour, a day, a week, a month, etc. There is no defined "enough time to continue playing it".

Moreover, it is impossible to state definitively how much power a process will run in the future.

Now, you *could* create some code that attempts to measure historical power consumption of an application (and how the user uses it, which may vary from person to person). You *could* use that information to make some educated guesses about how long the user could keep using that app. And you *could* find a way to present that information to the user.

All of that will require, at minimum, custom firmware. It is also very possible that it will require custom hardware that has fine-grained power consumption data collection, such as the Qualcomm MDP.

Comment: Thanks for the information .. but can you give me an idea on how will i code it? thank you for your help. and what is the "QUALCOMM MDP" ?

Comment: i didn't know how to start with the coding. I'm a newbie here in android. can you please help me with your recommendation about the historical power consumption of an application? pleasseee.

Comment: @RinggoLacunaDeJesus: If you are "a newbie here in android", you will not be able to do it without several years' more experience. You have to create custom firmware, which means going into the guts of the operating system's C/C++ code, making changes, and building the results. Those results will only work on your own phone, or on phones where you can replace the built-in Android with your own version of Android. You are welcome to visit http://source.android.com to learn more about this.

Comment: can you please help me? this is only our last problem in our thesis. i didn't know how to do it. please. I'm begging you. i saw the built in battery usage in android phone. that's what i want to do. but like i said i don't have any idea. so can you please help me? please..

Comment: @RinggoLacunaDeJesus: Talk to your thesis advisor and explain that what you wanted to do is not something that can be reasonably accomplished in the available time. Have your thesis advisor read this StackOverflow post and others you have asked on the subject.